# Parsing complex operands in boolean expressions in Python 2.7

Tags: parsing, python-2.7, pyparsing, boolean-expression

I am trying to modify the example code in [pyparsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/file/view/simpleBool.py/451074414/simpleBool.py) to handle operands that are key value pairs, like:

```
(Region:US and Region:EU) or (Region:Asia)
```

This is a boolean expression with three operands - Region:US, Region:EU and Region:Asia. If they were simple operands like x, y and z, I'd be good to go. I don't need to do any special processing on them to break up the key-value pairs. I need to treat the operand in its entirety as though it might have just been x, and need to assign truth values to it and evaluate the full expression.

How might I modify the following code to handle this:

```
#
# simpleBool.py
#
# Example of defining a boolean logic parser using
# the operatorGrammar helper method in pyparsing.
#
# In this example, parse actions associated with each
# operator expression will "compile" the expression
# into BoolXXX class instances, which can then
# later be evaluated for their boolean value.
#
# Copyright 2006, by Paul McGuire
# Updated 2013-Sep-14 - improved Python 2/3 cross-compatibility
#
from pyparsing import infixNotation, opAssoc, Keyword, Word, alphas

# define classes to be built at parse time, as each matching
# expression type is parsed
class BoolOperand(object):
    def __init__(self,t):
        self.label = t[0]
        self.value = eval(t[0])
    def __bool__(self):
        return self.value
    def __str__(self):
        return self.label
    __repr__ = __str__
    __nonzero__ = __bool__

class BoolBinOp(object):
    def __init__(self,t):
        self.args = t[0][0::2]
    def __str__(self):
        sep = " %s " % self.reprsymbol
        return "(" + sep.join(map(str,self.args)) + ")"
    def __bool__(self):
        return self.evalop(bool(a) for a in self.args)
    __nonzero__ = __bool__
    __repr__ = __str__

class BoolAnd(BoolBinOp):
    reprsymbol = '&'
    evalop = all

class BoolOr(BoolBinOp):
    reprsymbol = '|'
    evalop = any

class BoolNot(object):
    def __init__(self,t):
        self.arg = t[0][1]
    def __bool__(self):
        v = bool(self.arg)
        return not v
    def __str__(self):
        return "~" + str(self.arg)
    __repr__ = __str__
    __nonzero__ = __bool__

TRUE = Keyword("True")
FALSE = Keyword("False")
boolOperand = TRUE | FALSE | Word(alphas,max=1)
boolOperand.setParseAction(BoolOperand)

# define expression, based on expression operand and
# list of operations in precedence order
boolExpr = infixNotation( boolOperand,
    [
    ("not", 1, opAssoc.RIGHT, BoolNot),
    ("and", 2, opAssoc.LEFT,  BoolAnd),
    ("or",  2, opAssoc.LEFT,  BoolOr),
    ])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    p = True
    q = False
    r = True
    tests = [("p", True),
             ("q", False),
             ("p and q", False),
             ("p and not q", True),
             ("not not p", True),
             ("not(p and q)", True),
             ("q or not p and r", False),
             ("q or not p or not r", False),
             ("q or not (p and r)", False),
             ("p or q or r", True),
             ("p or q or r and False", True),
             ("(p or q or r) and False", False),
            ]

    print("p =", p)
    print("q =", q)
    print("r =", r)
    print()
    for t,expected in tests:
        res = boolExpr.parseString(t)[0]
        success = "PASS" if bool(res) == expected else "FAIL"
        print (t,'\n', res, '=', bool(res),'\n', success, '\n')
```

Instead of p, q, r, I'd like to use "Region:US", "Region:EU" and "Region:Asia." Any ideas?

**EDIT:** Using Paul McGuire's suggestion, I tried writing the following code which breaks on parsing:

```
#
# simpleBool.py
#
# Example of defining a boolean logic parser using
# the operatorGrammar helper method in pyparsing.
#
# In this example, parse actions associated with each
# operator expression will "compile" the expression
# into BoolXXX class instances, which can then
# later be evaluated for their boolean value.
#
# Copyright 2006, by Paul McGuire
# Updated 2013-Sep-14 - improved Python 2/3 cross-compatibility
#
from pyparsing import infixNotation, opAssoc, Keyword, Word, alphas

# define classes to be built at parse time, as each matching
# expression type is parsed
class BoolOperand(object):
    def __init__(self,t):
        self.label = t[0]
        self.value = validValues[t[0]]
    def __bool__(self):
        return self.value
    def __str__(self):
        return self.label
    __repr__ = __str__
    __nonzero__ = __bool__

class BoolBinOp(object):
    def __init__(self,t):
        self.args = t[0][0::2]
    def __str__(self):
        sep = " %s " % self.reprsymbol
        return "(" + sep.join(map(str,self.args)) + ")"
    def __bool__(self):
        return self.evalop(bool(a) for a in self.args)
    __nonzero__ = __bool__
    __repr__ = __str__

class BoolAnd(BoolBinOp):
    reprsymbol = '&'
    evalop = all

class BoolOr(BoolBinOp):
    reprsymbol = '|'
    evalop = any

class BoolNot(object):
    def __init__(self,t):
        self.arg = t[0][1]
    def __bool__(self):
        v = bool(self.arg)
        return not v
    def __str__(self):
        return "~" + str(self.arg)
    __repr__ = __str__
    __nonzero__ = __bool__

TRUE = Keyword("True")
FALSE = Keyword("False")
boolOperand = TRUE | FALSE | Word(alphas+":",max=1)
boolOperand.setParseAction(BoolOperand)

# define expression, based on expression operand and
# list of operations in precedence order
boolExpr = infixNotation( boolOperand,
    [
    ("not", 1, opAssoc.RIGHT, BoolNot),
    ("and", 2, opAssoc.LEFT,  BoolAnd),
    ("or",  2, opAssoc.LEFT,  BoolOr),
    ])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    validValues = {
        "Region:US": False,
        "Region:EU": True,
        "Type:Global Assets>24": True
    }
    tests = [("Region:US", True),
             ("Region:EU", False),
             ("Region:US and Region:EU", False),
             ("Region:US and not Region:EU", True),
             ("not not Region:US", True),
             ("not(Region:US and Region:EU)", True),
             ("Region:EU or not Region:US and Type:Global Assets>24", False),
             ("Region:EU or not Region:US or not Type:Global Assets>24", False),
             ("Region:EU or not (Region:US and Type:Global Assets>24)", False),
             ("Region:US or Region:EU or Type:Global Assets>24", True),
             ("Region:US or Region:EU or Type:Global Assets>24 and False", True),
             ("(Region:US or Region:EU or Type:Global Assets>24) and False", False),
            ]

    print("Region:US =", validValues["Region:US"])
    print("Region:EU =", validValues["Region:EU"])
    print("Type:Global Assets>24 =", validValues["Type:Global Assets>24"])
    print()
    for t,expected in tests:
        res = boolExpr.parseString(t)[0]
        success = "PASS" if bool(res) == expected else "FAIL"
        print (t,'\n', res, '=', bool(res),'\n', success, '\n')
```

Thanks to Paul McGuire's help, here is the solution:

```
boolOperand = TRUE | FALSE | Combine(Word(alphas)+":"+quotedString) | Word(alphas+":<>")
```

This does the parsing as I wanted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two parts to making this change: changing the parser, and then changing the post-parsing behavior to accommodate these new values.

To parse operands that are not just simple 1-character names, change this line in the parser:

```
boolOperand = TRUE | FALSE | Word(alphas,max=1)
```

The simplest (but not strictest would be to just change it to:

```
boolOperand = TRUE | FALSE | Word(alphas+":")
```

But this would accept, in addition to your valid values of "Region:US" or "TimeZone:UTC", presumably invalid values like "XouEWRL:sdlkfj", ":sldjf:ljsdf:sdljf", and even ":::::::". If you want to tighten up the parser, you could enforce the key entry to:

```
valid_key = oneOf("Region Country City State ZIP")
valid_value = Word(alphas+"_")
valid_kv = Combine(valid_key + ":" + valid_value)
boolOperand = TRUE | FALSE | valid_kv
```

That should take care of the parser.

Second, you will need to change how this entry is evaluated after the parsing is done. In my example, I was emphasizing the parsing part, not the evaluating part, so I left this to simply call the eval() builtin. In your case, you will probably need to initialize a dict of valid values for each acceptable key-value pair, and then change the code in BoolOperand to do a dict lookup instead of calling eval. (This has the added benefit of *not* calling eval() with user-entered data, which has all kinds of potential for security problems.)

Comment: Thanks for responding, Paul! I tried this, but the parsing fails with your suggested change.

`boolOperand = TRUE | FALSE | Word(alphas+":")`

results in the exception `pyparsing.ParseException: Expected W:(abcd...) (at char 1), (line:1, col:2)`. Here is the first test that cause the failure: `tests = [("Region:US", True)` I also made the changes to the evaluation part as you suggested, but the code fails at the parsing step itself. Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: I just made this change in the parser without making any change in the BoolOperand class, and successfully parsed the string, but the parse action failed when trying to eval "Region:US", as one would expect. So I suspect there is an error in your modification to the BoolOperand class. Try using Python's pdb debugger, and set a breakpoint inside the `BoolOperand.__init__` method, and step through the logic to make sure it works properly.  If you need more help, post your modified BoolOperand class.

Comment: You left "max=1" in the Word definition, take that off.

Comment: That works great, but it still barfs on something like: Key:Value, where Value has special characters, e.g. "MyKey:X>24"

Comment: Well of course it does. pyparsing is not a mind-reader. If you want to accept more characters in the operand, you will have to add them to the string used to initialize the Word.

Comment: I did that, but wasn't able to get it to work. Here's what I tried: `boolOperand = TRUE | FALSE | Word(alphas+":><")`. However this still barfs as the the operand is 'Key:Some value with spaces and < or >'. The spaces mess it up. If I add a space in the word definition, then the expression parsing gets messed up. I suppose I can keep it simple and not use spaces in the value, but it would be nice to know if this can be done simply.

Comment: No, do not add spaces to operand, you will completely mess up the parsing logic. Once you add spaces, then your operand becomes much more complicated, more of an expression in itself. If you want spaces in the key, try Key:"value with spaces in it", and expand operand to accept `Combine(Word(alphas) + ':' + quotedString)`.

Comment: By the way, these changes are departing radically from your original simple extension to accept operands like "Region:xxx". It may be time to revisit the grammar design instead of just hacking more bits onto this one.

Comment: Not sure if you meant spaces in the value, but I tried the Combine like so: `boolOperand = TRUE | FALSE | Combine(Word(alphas+":"+quotedString))` and a test like so: `('Type:"Global Assets>24"', True)`. This crashes. I also tried `boolOperand = TRUE | FALSE | Combine(Word(alphas+":<>"+quotedString))` and this also does not work. The error is in parsing the word definition `TypeError: object of type 'And' has no len()` in pyparsing line 1705.

Comment: This should handle your cases with special characters and no spaces, or a value in a quoted string containing spaces, or anything else: `boolOperand = TRUE | FALSE | Combine(Word(alphas)+":"+quotedString) | Word(alphas+":<>")`